# Алгоритм рисования сглаженной линии

Tags: алгоритм, c++

Здравствуйте!

Такая проблема:
1) нужно попиксельно нарисовать линию;
2) толщина линии должна задаваться параметром;
3) линия должна быть сглаженная;
4) алгоритм рисования должен быть очень быстрым, прямо таки сглаживать нужно "на лету"(без мультисемплирования и вообще желательно без буфферизации).

Функция рисования пикселя: `SetPix(int x, int y, int color); color` задается так: `0xRRGGBBAA;`.
Написал свой алгоритм, он рисует линию разной толщины. Толщина разная, но на концах линия получается обрезанной:

[image]

Подскажите алгоритм, исходники, что позволяют добиться желаемого результата)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Это называется [алгоритмом Брезенхема](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C0%EB%E3%EE%F0%E8%F2%EC_%C1%F0%E5%E7%E5%ED%F5%FD%EC%E0).

Но в вашем случае требуется модифицированный алгоритм Брезенхема, меняющий интенсивность окрашивания точки, - иногда называется [алгоритм Ву Сяолиня](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C0%EB%E3%EE%F0%E8%F2%EC_%C2%F3).

Примеры обоих алгоритмов в [статье на Хабре](http://habrahabr.ru/post/185086/).

Comment: Алгоритм Ву Сяолиня, вроде, и то, что нужно, но в сети нигде нет примера, где можно варьировать толщину линии.

Comment: @Alerr, дальше уже сами :)